# audio NSData to NSString encoding

Tags: ios, ios7, parse-platform

I'm using Parse as a backend and it doesn't like `NSData`.  I have an array that I need to store  that holds the data of different audio files in each of its elements.  I know I can convert my data to `NSString`, but I'm not sure what kind of encoding is appropriate.  The strings will need to be converted back to an `NSData` objects.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

PFFile is the class you want, you can create it from NSData if you want to save binary files: https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFFile.html

Comment: Putting parse aside, what would be the proper way of converting audio data into a string?  What type of encoding would you use?

Comment: @brosef [base 64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) comes to mind, although I might be concerned by space and bandwidth when used with audio.